# Resetting AWS params to default params

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Basic plan AWS account that I use for doing some labs and PoCs since I start doing some Devops.

Lately I'm no more able to connect to created instance via SSH (despite that I create a rule for port 22) after changing a couple of network params.

Is there a way to reset my AWS account so I get back to my default configuration ?

Comment: By reset, I presume you mean delete all AWS resources like compute instances, databases, IAM credentials etc. You could take a look at https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke but be very careful you understand what it does. Make sure that you have some way to log in (e.g. root credentials) if you delete IAM users (and roles).

Comment: Can I have more than one root crendetials ? The account that I want to reset is the root and only one that's why I'm asking this question

Comment: You want to reset the AWS account, as in delete resources. That's nothing to do with the root user.

Comment: You said that I make sur that I have some way to log in !

Comment: There is one root user. When you created the AWS account, you were given credentials for that user. Subsequent to that, you could have done a variety of things that would make logging in as the root user impossible: forgot the password, disabled the root account, configured MFA on the root user and lost the MFA device, and more. I'm saying that you need to make sure that you are able to log in as the root user *if* you are going to delete IAM users. The root user cannot be deleted (but you could have made it unusable, as mentioned earlier).

Comment: Ok that's clear now, actually all the other users that I created doesn't matter.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I used [aws-nuke](https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke) but I couldn't remove all my resources for some reason (I might had missed something).

But when I changed region from Paris to Frankfurt I was able to create EC2 instances and access them via SSH.